# Test case tracking app

Tags: webapp-rec, tracking

Can you recommend me a free web app for our testing and QA team to track progress of various test cases.

Comment: "Recommendation" questions like this really should be marked Community Wiki.

Comment: At least whats done with all the other questions: "List of"-style questions are marked as CW (voted on popularity) and "Recommendation"-style questions not (voted on descriptions, only recommending the best one, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [Hudson](https://hudson.dev.java.net/), easy to set up and easy to use :)

Answer (score 2):

I once looked into [Testopia](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/), a test case management extension for Bugzilla. Of course it requires Bugzilla and if you use a different issue tracker already then it might not be the first choice.

Mozilla uses another application too, [Litmus](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Litmus), which they use (used?) to test their own applications.

Both can be installed on a local server. I guess, that's what you prefer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a general test case management system, take a look at a list of [open source tools here](http://www.opensourcetestmanagement.com/). However, in case you also consider commercial tools (which most prefer because the open source tools are not really user friendly in this space, unlike other areas such as bug tracking tools), feel free to take a look at our tool [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gurock.com](http://www.gurock.com/images/feature/testrail-screenshot-v2.png))</sub>

Another poster mentioned Hudson: Hudson is a continuous integration tool and it's great to track test results from automated tests during software builds, but it does not really help with functional/manual testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a tool I have been developing [TestLodge - Test Case Management Tool](http://www.testlodge.com)

TestLodge is a relatively new hosted tool that is designed to be a lot simpler than traditional software by only providing the essentials to get the job done well.
The system focuses on helping you create your test plans, creating and managing your test suites, requirements and cases along with allowing you to easily perform multiple test runs and generate reports.

This is a commercial product, but it does have a free price plan that may fit your needs.

As always, if you have any suggestions on how we can improve the tool, please get in touch with us.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Old Post, but still replying this in case some one finds this Post later and need some info

This is a tool which we (my company Divistra) has created.

Try
http://dots.divistra.com

1. It is a free Online web based Testcase management/Agile Project/ Defect Tracking tool for Distributed Team
2. it lets you track Multiple Unlimited Project Project/Unlimited User
3. Simple workflow and user interface
4. Tracking User Stories, Defect and Test cases.
5. Makes you awesome at what you do.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the above mentioned service. Otherwise, your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!